# Reading NFC Tag in Unity3D

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, nfc

I would like to get the text string saved on an NFC tag in Unity. I'm not experienced with developing for Android, it seems there was already success doing this but it seems to involve extensive use of the Android SDK and Eclipse, neither I'm familiar with.

I found also this thread though the source code is incomplete and I'm not sure how to declare the variables used in this if statement: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/162834-AndroidJavaObject-as-array-for-NFC-access?p=1115826&posted=1#post1115826

Any usings that I need to import in order to use this snippet and the "var" type variable mentioned in the first post?

OP hasn't been answering all the other questions for over a year now.
I hoped someone here might have an answer for NFC in general.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pablo from Twinsprite has put [a full working example project on GitHub](https://github.com/twisprite-developers/unity-android-nfc-plugin)

And he has written a very detailed [blog-post](http://blog.twinsprite.com/2014/05/10/nfc-android-java-plugin-for-unity-3d.html) about how to create the required plugin yourself.

Works great for me!

Comment: I can't test it right now but thats looking really good, thanks.

Comment: Its working but having kind of mixed results. Sometimes it doesn't read tags anymore after reading a few and it takes about 2 seconds from successful read to actually getting the nfc string :/
That's on a Nexus 7.

Answer (score 0):

For someone else reading in the future, they have an updated link:
[The new Link](https://github.com/twisprite-developers/unity-nfc-plugin)
I am working with this right now and I will keep you updated